# Can you use .cshmtl-pages in a existing webforms asp.net site?

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have an existing site in webforms asp.net, but now I want to make pages more like mvc or like classic asp, without the hassle with postbacks and viewstate. 
So is it possible to create pure .cshtml-pages in webforms-asp.net?

Comment: Take a look at the blogengine.net source, i know that uses razor for some of the themes. http://blogengine.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/26c826f27adf Not sure if you can get round the postback model though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question should be.

> Can I Use webforms and MVC in a single asp.net project?.

Then I would say. **Yes**

Comment: Yeah I could make a new asp.net mvc site and add all my existing webform-pages.